# funcao soma_ll que recebe uma lista de listas e retorna a soma de todos os números

Tags: python, recursão, soma

```
def soma_ll(lista):

     return  lista[0] + soma_ll(lista[1:])
```

Por que o meu teste não roda?

```
def test_600_soma_ll(self):

    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([1,2,3]),6)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([1,2,3,4]),10)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([-1,-2,-3,-4]),-10)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([1]),1)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([]),0)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([-3]),-3)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[],[]]),0)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[1],[2]]),3)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[[1,2,3],[4,5],11],9,8]),43)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[[1,2,3],[4,5],11,4],9,8,4]),51)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[-1],[1]]),0)
    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[1],[[2],1]]),4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Não funciona porque chega uma hora em que a sub-lista gerada é vazia e ocorre um  [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError). Por exemplo, se a lista é `[1, 2]`:

- a função soma `lista[0]` (o número 1) com `soma_ll(lista[1:])` (ou seja, `soma_ll([2])`)

  - `soma_ll([2])` soma `lista[0]` (o número 2) com `soma_ll(lista[1:])` (ou seja, `soma_ll([])`)

    - `soma_ll([])` tenta pegar `lista[0]`, mas como a lista é vazia, não existe o índice zero, então ocorre um `IndexError` - [veja](https://ideone.com/mMDx1e)

Para corrigir, você deve colocar uma condição de parada, que é quando a lista está vazia:

```
def soma_ll(lista):
    if not lista:
        return 0
    return  lista[0] + soma_ll(lista[1:])

print(soma_ll([1, 2, 3])) # 6
```

Se a lista é vazia, retorna zero (pois em uma lista vazia, a soma dos seus elementos - inexistentes - é zero).

`if not lista` verifica se a lista é vazia, porque [listas vazias são consideradas `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Mas você também poderia fazer `if len(lista) == 0`.

---

E sempre vale lembrar que recursão **não** é a melhor forma de somar os elementos de uma lista. Para isso já existe até [algo pronto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) na linguagem, bastando fazer `sum(lista)`.

---

Outro detalhe é que em muitos casos você está somando listas dentro de listas (dentro de listas, dentro de listas, etc). Neste caso você precisa verificar se o elemento sendo somado é um número ou uma lista (e se for uma lista, deve chamar a função recursiva novamente):

```
def soma_ll(lista):
    if not lista:
        return 0
    if isinstance(lista[0], list):
        sum = soma_ll(lista[0])
    else:
        sum = lista[0]
    return sum + soma_ll(lista[1:])

print(soma_ll([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], 11, 4], 9, 8, 4])) # 51
print(soma_ll([[], []])) # 0
```

Aqui eu simplifiquei bastante, pois se não for lista, eu considero que é número.

Comment: não sei quer tá acontecendo meu velho está parando nesse teste    self.assertEqual(soma_ll([[],[]]),0)  e já modifiquei  em várias vezes dar nisso não tá passando tudo.

Comment: @RômuloSilvaSouzaSantos Atualizei a resposta

Comment: brigado cara pela explição